# How to add custom checking using jquery form wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, formwizard

I want to add a customized validation function into the form using jquery form wizard. the form has got a dropdown box. If you select age group 4 to 5, it alerts "answer one". If you select age group 5 to 6, it alerts "answer two". else, it alerts "anser three". I have a lot of this type conditional questions to filter my answer. What is the best way to do? Can I make the function in an external js file?

Comment: ya.... that's better...

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery addmethod` for this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("agegroup", function(value, element) { 
    // you code to test age groups range 
}, "Please Enter correct range");
```

Read Docs http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Hopefully, it works I never used it, but I am shore that it will work.

Comment: thx for your answer. I have had a look at the addmethod. But what my form has is a set of tree type of questions. There are like 13 questions, if you select 1.A 2.A 3.B.... you get result 1. If you select 1.B 2.A 3.B.... you get another result. I dont quite understand how to apply it using addmethod. If I set my form as the "value" in addMethod, how do I get dropdown box value?